# JasperReports: exporting the report to csv format

Tags: spring, jasper-reports

I am working with *JasperReports 4.5.0*, *Spring 3.0.5 RELEASE*. I am exporting my JR report in *pdf*, *html*, *csv* formats. With *pdf*, *html* the report is generating fine.

But when i am exporting my report in csv it is displaying all the fields and values in one column only. My code flow is exactly like [this link](http://chathurangat.blogspot.in/2012/02/jasperreport-with-spring-mvc-fully.html).

Below is the example how I am getting now.

```
|                     A                  |    B   | C    | D    |
|S.No,IPAddress,TotalDuration,TotalBdrCount  |        |      |      |
|1,null,266082,null                      |        |      |      |
 2,null,null,null                        |        |       |     |
 3,null,null,null                        |        |       |     |
 4,null,null,null                        |        |       |     |
```

Where ***S.No,IPAddress,TotalDuration,TotalBdrCount*** are the column headers and **1,null,266082,null** are the values to the respective columns.

But my requirement is

```
|  A   |     B    |       C      |       D      |
| S.No | IPAddress | TotalDuration | TotalBdrCount |
```

I think you understood my problem. For this am i need to set any parameters? I am not getting. Can any one help me out regarding this issue.

Comment: The *csv* it is [Comma-Separated Values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values). It is just a plain text contains values with separators. You should post the first 5 rows from your resulting *csv* file. What viewer (editor) are you using to view *csv* file?

Comment: Thanks for giving the reply.I am using MS excel to view the csv file.I have this requirement thats why i am first trying with sample.So i have only one row right now.This is a very urgent requirement because we have a demo on my project.

Comment: Can your post (in your question) the first 4-6 rows from the resulting *csv*? I think that problem in separator or you should be more accurate during opening file in Excel.

Comment: Hi i have improved the question right now i dont have much data to test.Thats why the report is like that.I am opening the csv with MS excel using character set as using Unicode(UTF-8).

Comment: You should open *csv* file in simple text editor (Notepad, for example - not in Excel) and just copy 5 rows from file and paste this rows in your question.

Comment: Hey i got it.Thank You for giving the replies...